# Атрибуты класса (self и class_name)

Tags: python, классы, атрибуты

Почему при обращении к атрибуту класса `car_count` через `self` и `Car` получаются разные результаты?

```
class Car:
    car_count = 1

    def start(self, name, model):
        print("Двигатель заведен")
        self.name = name
        self.model = model
        self.car_count += 1
        print(self.car_count)
        print(Car.car_count)


car = Car()
car.start("Car1", "Model2")
```

Вывод получается следующий:

```
Двигатель заведен
2
1
```

`self.car_count` и `Car.car_count` это разные атрибуты\поля класса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При обращение `Car.car_count` вы обращаетесь к полю класса. Если данное поле не переопределять, то оно всегда будет равно еденице, как константа

Если вы вызываете `car = Car()`, то вы создаете уже объект класса, который имеет свое значение для `car_count`, которое вы назначаете через `self`

Ещё проще - это два совершенно разных объекта.

Comment: Да, только почему как константа?
Если сделать так:

car.start("Car1", "n2", "Model2")
print(Car.car_count)
Car.car_count = 5
print(Car.car_count)
car.start("Car1", "n2", "Model2")

Comment: Значение car_count можно изменить

Comment: Конечно можно, с этим никто не спорит. В python при большом желании можно все переопределить, в том числе и константы

Answer (score 2):

Через экземпляр класса вы можете обращаться к полям самого класса, пока у экземпляра нет своих таких же полей. Но как только вы в экземпляре класса поменяете поле, оно потеряет связь с полем класса и начнёт жить своей жизнью. Иллюстрация:

```
class A:
    a = 1

print(A.a)
# 1
a = A()
print(A.a, a.a)
# 1 1 <- после создания экземпляра значение поля одинаковое
A.a += 1
print(A.a, a.a)
# 2 2 <- изменили поле класса - поле экземпляра тоже поменялось
a.a += 1
print(A.a, a.a)
# 2 3 <- после изменения поля экземпляра его связь с классом пропала
A.a += 2
print(A.a, a.a)
# 4 3 <- и связь класса с экземпляром тоже пропала, поля полностью независимы
```